# Теряются flash-messages при редиректе yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, redirect

После перехода с yii на yii2 я обнаружил проблему: если установить `flash-message` и сделать в контроллере редирект, то на новой странице `flash-message` не отобразится. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->redirect()` не останавливает выполнения.

Рассмотрим [пример простого action в yii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L885) первой версии:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) && $model->save()) {
       $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
       $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[И для yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Response.php#L751):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

На первый взгляд, разница незаметна, но она есть. Обратите внимание, что у нас в коде добавилось ключевое слово `return`. И перед `render` и перед `redirect`.

По сути, остановку в action мы теперь производим руками.

Не забываем ставить `return` и все будет хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

При конфигурации приложения в components нужно задать session

```
    'components' => [
       'session' => [
          'name' => 'example-session-name',
       ],
    ]
```